# Не удалось завершить операцию. Интерфейс не поддерживается. Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Хочу познакомится с Xamarin, для этого установил VS2017 Community, до этого использовал VS2012, как я понял в ней использовать его не получится. В тестовом проекте у меня появилась ошибка [image: Xamarin error] (Не удалось найти тип или пространство имен..) при попытке добавить ссылку на сборку появляется ошибка "Не удалось завершить операцию. Интерфейс не поддерживается.". Как исправить проблему или это из за бесплатной версии VS?
Создал проект winforms, попытался добавить ссылку там ошибка идентичная.

Comment: Уставили ли вы необходимые компоненты, когда ставили vs( там галочки ставишь)?

Comment: "Создал проект winforms, попытался добавить ссылку там ошибка идентичная" - a каким макаром вообще так можно делать? Для работы с Xamarin есть спец. типы проектов, их и надо использовать. Xamarin бесплатен и доступен в VS2017 Community. Вероятно, вы не установили нужные разделы при установке студии.

Comment: @Bulson я имел ввиду что и для winforms и для xamarin проектов ошибка одинаковая

Answer (score 2):

Как Вы устанавливали Xamarin? Если Вы устанавливали вначале Visual Studio, а затем Xamarin, то этот способ не подходит. Этот инструмент устанавливается *вместе* с IDE! Прочитайте статью [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/setup-and-install).

Если же Вы все установили так, как надо, то прочитайте [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/verify-your-xamarin-environment). В разных версиях VS алгоритмы действия различаются.

Comment: У вас все ссылки даны для VS2015, а речь идет о VS2017.

Comment: @Bulson, поменял ссылки на VS2017.

Comment: @ДаниилЧижевский ставил галочку как в первой ссылке во время установки VS2017

Comment: @Winteriscoming, а Вы уверены в том, что стерли все следы от предыдущей VS?

Comment: @ДаниилЧижевский я не удалял предыдущую, первый раз слышу что бы они конфликтовали.

Comment: @Winteriscoming, конечно, они будут конфликтовать!

Comment: Вы хоть посмотрели вторую ссылку? Там тоже может быть полезная для Вас информация.